# Clicks in the html page ignored on tablet

Tags: javascript, html, css, performance, mobile

I am working on html page and having problem with performance (?)
You can see my sample page. When I open it on tablet (I tried iPad 2 and Android tablets), and tap cells as fast as I can, only every second tap is handled. What am I doing wrong?

On the google mail, I tried tapping on the stars on mails (again, as fast as possible), they ended up all activated.

I also measured time needed to tap 10 stars (on both my page and gmail). In both cases, I did it in little under 3 seconds. So I was tapping the same speed on both pages.

```js
var count = 0;
function clicked(el) {
  el.style.backgroundColor = "black";
  count++;
  counter.textContent = count;
}

window.onload = function() {
  for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    var row = document.createElement("tr");
    tbl.appendChild(row);

    var cell = document.createElement("td");
    row.appendChild(cell);

    cell.onclick = function() { clicked(this); };
  }
}
```

```css
td {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<table id="tbl">
</table>
<h1 id="counter"></h1>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most mobile browsers (iOS Safari, Android Browser, Chrome Mobile, etc) have delay about *300ms* between a physical tap and the firing of a `click` event by default. It's necessary to *double tap* handling (*zoom*). You can't fire `click` event in these cases more often than one time in *300ms*.

If you want to fire your function immediately by *tap* in mobile browser, you should use [Touch Events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch_events).

**Simple example:**

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sergdenisov/mzhpzzrL/2/)

```js
var count = 0;
var tbl = document.getElementById('tbl');
var counter = document.getElementById('counter');
var tapping = false;

function click() {
    this.style.backgroundColor = 'black';
    count++;
    counter.textContent = count;
}

function touchStart() {
    tapping = true;
}

function touchCancel() {
    tapping = false;
}

function touchEnd(e) {
    click.apply(this);
    e.preventDefault();
    tapping = false;
}

for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    var row = document.createElement('tr');
    tbl.appendChild(row);
    
    var cell = document.createElement('td');
    row.appendChild(cell);
    
    cell.addEventListener('click', click, false);
    cell.addEventListener('touchstart', touchStart, false);
    cell.addEventListener('touchmove', touchCancel, false);
    cell.addEventListener('touchcancel', touchCancel, false);
    cell.addEventListener('touchend', touchEnd, false);
}
```

```css
td {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<table id="tbl"></table>
<h1 id="counter"></h1>
```

Also, you could don't change your code and use [FastClick](https://github.com/ftlabs/fastclick) library. It removes delay for most popular browsers, you need only [attach it](https://github.com/ftlabs/fastclick#usage).

Comment: Thanks! Working like a charm :)

Comment: my first question, trying to find how :S

Comment: @Slimacik I advice this article for more understanding — https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2013/12/300ms-tap-delay-gone-away.